# Only in the context of a <Router> component error on import outside project root

Tags: react-router, create-react-app, storybook

I have two React projects.

- Project "app" contains the main project.
- Project "sb" contains a Storybook project.

The dependencies have been made the same, both projects are created with CRA.

```
app/
  components/
    SampleComp.tsx
sb/
  components/
    SampleComp.tsx
  stories/
    SampleComp.stories.tsx
```

Both `SampleComp.tsx` are exactly the same in code.

- When I import `SampleComp.tsx` from the `sb/components` folder, it's working.
- When I import `SampleComp.tsx` from the `app/components` folder, it's NOT working.

The latter fails with the following error in Storybook:
"useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component."

In the stories, I wrap the component in the `MemoryRouter`.

**SampleComp.tsx (both)**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export function SampleComp() {
  return (
    <div>
      Home page
          <Link to="/test">Test</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**SampleComp.stories.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from "@storybook/react";
// import { SampleComp } from "../../app/components/SampleComp"; // not working
import { SampleComp } from "../components/SampleComp"; // works!
import { MemoryRouter } from "react-router";

export default {
  title: "SampleComp",
  component: SampleComp,
  parameters: {
    layout: "fullscreen",
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof SampleComp>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof SampleComp> = (args) => (
  <MemoryRouter>
    <SampleComp />
  </MemoryRouter>
);

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

Why doesn't it work the same?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why you have a completely separate storybook directory? Assuming both "app" and "sb" are directories in the `"/src"` directory I don't see any reason for the exports/imports to not work as expected.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your comment! The folders aren't in a common src directory, but they're both part of a monorepo. Actually, the dev lead doesn't want Storybook in the main project because CRA is (supposed to be) easily updatable. However, Storybook alters the Webpack dependency when installed in the CRA app.

Comment: Ooof... well, I can speak from personal experience working with a monorepo where one of the repos was supposed to be a component library with Storybook and after a couple years of it just not working we merged the "component library" into the main app repo so we could write better components and not decouple presentation components from container components. And our stories worked with our components(*!!!*).

Comment: Basically it sounds like you should try taking a look at your directories/projects/repos and see if setting `react` and `react-dom` as peer dependencies helps. From our effort it was that each repo's code was build using their own "instance" of React. We never did get it sorted out. Best of luck to you and your team.

Comment: @DrewReese Your comments make me feel very hopeful, haha, but thank you! Both projects include and use the same react, react-dom and react-router-dom dependencies/versions. Both projects were created using the CRA build not long after each other.  If I solve it, I'll definitely write an answer. Thanks again!